# Regex literal word with escape character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Alright so in javascript in trying to replace the following tag with .replace

`</font>`

right now im using

```
/<\/font>/mg
```

However I'm trying to make it match that exact sequence not just every piece. I could be wrong and it is already doing that but I wanted to ask anyway

Comment: It does. the m modifier is useless, remove it.

Comment: Why don't you simply test it and see if it works instead of posting a question ?!

Answer (score -1):

Check it weather is it working?

```
/<\/font>/g
```

Also provide some sample code snippet for clarity.